# Closing Android databases across Parallel Threads

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I am asking this question in context of a problem in my app, about which I find it difficult to create an exact question. But I do have a lead.

I do have parallel threads running and my problem revolves around the case where running queries on database returns **NullpointerException** on the initialized database instance.

So what I want to know is that if you initialize an instance of a database by **db.getWritableDatabase()** in 2 parallel threads, does closing the database in one thread by **db.close()**, closes it in the other thread ? infact across the application level ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create singleton of SQLiteOpenHelper/**db** (you did not specify what class **db** is) which would return you only one instance and then you could check if db is closed or not.

I had similar problem and in the end 2 parallel threads and 1 database ? You are asking for problems.

You cannot safely have 2 actions operating with database at the same time.

```
/**
 * Returns a writable database instance in order not to open and close many
 * SQLiteDatabase objects simultaneously
 *
 * @return a writable instance to SQLiteDatabase
 */
public SQLiteDatabase getMyWritableDatabase() {
    if ((db == null) || (!db.isOpen())) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return db;
}

@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
        db = null;
    }
}
```